# Factor Analysis Rotation types in R

Tags: rotation, factor-analysis

I have tried looking in the help in R about the types of rotations to use for factor analysis. I am using the function **factanal**. The default is varimax. The other types of rotations are "none" and "promax". Are there others like oblique and orthogonal or are there only 3 rotation options in R?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other packages in R  - such as qmethod - include other rotations. Oblique rotation options - such as promox or oblimin - seem to be possible but seem to have issues (as in, they run and display results but use the same tables as varimax instead of the structure and pattern tables).

So I'd be surprised if other packages didn't have additional rotation options.